# Attribute one-liner without commas?

Tags: c#, attributes

Today I noticed something strange that I first thought it wouldn't compile:

```
[Serializable Obsolete]
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Notice the comma is missing between serializable and obsolete. It gives an error but it still compiles! Why is this? Do attributes even work like this?

Comment: That's nice to know. It seems you can chain attributes inside single `[` `]` group using space as separator, e.g. `[Serializable Obsolete MyA MyB]` (where `MyA` and `MyB` are custom attributes). Typically (what most people are used to) each attribute is enclosed into own `[` `]`.

Comment: I tried your code and checked the applied attributes via reflection. They both seem to be applied to the class. _What_ is the error you get and _who_ is raising it? It's obviously no compiler error (otherwise compilation would not be successful). I get an "Attribute is not valid on this declaration type" error, it seems it's ReSharper who is raising this and it thinks I wanted to apply the first attribute to the second. Anyway, the no-comma syntax seems valid in c#.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Rene already said that resharper is giving this error. I suspended resharper and now I don't get any error at all. So this seems to be perfectly fine syntax in C# for attributes.

Why resharper is giving this error I do not know however. Sure it could be weird syntax and against conventions but that's what warnings are for not errors.